# Why $u \cdot v \leq |u \cdot v|$ holds?

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces

This is a very basic question:

Why 
$$u \cdot v \leq |u \cdot v|$$
holds?

I was trying to use the dot product rule to explain this, but it seems that the dot product rule gives a conclusion as $$u \cdot v \leq ||u|| ||v||$$ But that is not exactly the same as the above inequality.

Answer (score 8):

Since $u \cdot v$ is a scalar, what you want to prove basically amounts to:

$$x \le |x|$$

where $x$ is a real number (or an element in an ordered field).

Answer (score 0):

Note:
$$u\cdot v =|u|\cdot |v|\cdot \cos{\theta}\le |u|\cdot |v|\cdot |\cos{\theta}|=||u|\cdot |v|\cdot \cos{\theta}|=|u\cdot v|.$$